# T-SQL query to find the most consecutive number of under par scores in a golf database

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, gaps-and-islands

Let's say we have a SQL Server database for our golf course. We have a table called `Results` that has the following columns (all `INT NOT NULL`):

- `PlayerId`
- `RoundId`
- `HoleId`
- `Score`

We also have a table called `Holes` that has the following columns (all `INT NOT NULL`):

- `HoleId`
- `Number` (1 through 18)
- `Par` (3, 4 or 5)

We want to write a single query that will find who has had the most consecutive under par scores (hole in one, birdie, eagle, double eagle) in a single round. The query should return the following info:

- `PlayerId`
- `RoundId`
- `NumberOfConsecutiveUnderParScores` (an `INT`)
- `UnderParHoleNumbers` (a `VARCHAR` containing comma separated values in ascending order)

I could not come up with anything useful. Maybe using a recursive common table expression is the way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s a gaps and islands problem, where an island is a series of hole scores under par for a given player and round.

We can identify the islands with a window sum, then aggregate and sort.

```
select playerId, roundId,
    count(*) NumberOfConsecutiveUnderParHoles,
    string_agg(number, ', ') within group (order by number) UnderParHoleNumbers
from (
    select r.*, h.number,
        sum(case when r.score < h.par then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by r.playerId, r.roundId order by h.number) grp
    from results r
    inner join holes h on h.holeId = r.holeId
) t
group by playerId, roundId, grp
order by count(*) desc
```

If you just want the longest under-par streak, you can turn the select to `select top (1) with ties`.

Comment: `rows unbounded preceding` might be wise, just in case there are duplicates in the ordering. It's also faster.

Comment: @Charlieface: I am not sure what you mean, isn’t it the default frame already? *If ROWS/RANGE is not specified but ORDER BY is specified, RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW is used as default for window frame*: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#rows-or-range

Comment: `RANGE` and `ROWS` are subtly different, the difference is only apparent if the `ORDER BY` is not over unique columns. See eg https://stevestedman.com/2013/04/rows-and-range-preceding-and-following/

Comment: @Charlieface: oh I see, and thanks for the useful link. I wouldn’t expect duplicate holes by the same player in the same round though ;)

Comment: True but like I said: it's best to do so just in case (you don't want someone copying the code for somewhere else and forgetting it) plus it's faster anyway